# How to check if image is available in ruby?

Tags: ruby, image

I guess this is easy, I seem to be missing  something simple.
I need to read an image and then display it which i do as follows, I should skip the code if the image is not available.

```
 stu_image ="/admin_num.jpg"

 if !stu_image 
         code for displaying the image
 end
```

But, this is not working. Could somebody help with this please.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just testing if the file exists?

```
stu_image ="/admin_num.jpg"
FileTest.exists?(RAILS_ROOT + stu_image ) #  < rails 3.0
FileTest.exists?(Rails.root + stu_image ) # >= rails 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you're just saving a string, not the image.

```
this_dir = File.dirname( __FILE__ )
file = File.expand_path( "admin_num.jpg", this_dir )
```

Answer (score 0):

See File#exists? here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-exists-3F